# Changing numeric language from konsole in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

how to change the numeric language to English from terminal & why the games are not working?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to change your `locale` settings.

1. Type `locale` in the console and observer what comes up (Note if LC_ALL= is set to something, this over rides all other settings).
2. If you want to change the numbers to english decimal (en_US.UTF-8), enter the following:

   `su -` (switch to root)

   `export LC_NUMBERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`

Try it out now and see.

Environment variables implement the locale codes. For example LANG=en_US.UTF-8 specifies that the computer uses US English with a UTF-8 encoding when displaying information.

Note: Type in `locale -a` to ensure you have the en_US.UTF-8 installed. If now use POSIX if you have that (I believe this is nessary but I am starting to doubt it now, most distro's will have that even if it isn't shown?)